# How can I read and modify a file's bytes using NASM assembly, with C++ for opening/closing the file?

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, file-io, nasm

Using C++ and NASM Assembly for a 32-bit program in Linux CentOS.

I want to open a file with C++, and modify it using NASM Assembly.

I had *heard* that you could create an `fstream`, and send its pointer as a parameter to a function in NASM, then you can operate over the bytes in that pointer.

The above doesn't seem to work for me, because sending the pointer to a `fstream` to NASM doesn't seem to yield the bytes in the file. The most I could do is read the bytes in the file, put them in a `char` vector and send it as a parameter to my NASM function, but the modifications I do there would not affect the file, right?

The way I am getting the bytes is the one described in http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/, under "Binary Files".

How can I read and modify a file's bytes using NASM  assembly, with C++ for opening/closing the file?

Comment: Ok, so not really an answer, but WHY would you want to read a file in assembler that was opened in C++? The C/C++ interface is quite complex to deal with in assembler. If you want to do this, get the pure filehandle by using `open` or `create` system calls, and then use the `read` and `write` system calls.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: It's for a college assignment - I understand this isn't practical at all.

Comment: The big question here, I think, is *do you really need to use assembler*? Today's C++ compilers are very good at optimizations, and depending on what you're doing it might even be *much* easier to do it all as a single C++ program. This seems to be a prime example of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Exactly what is your college assignment. To pass a `fstream` is definitely NOT an easy way to deal with the problem. Modifying the buffer (as Joachim suggests) or using primitive file operations are two of your options.

Comment: Obviously, another option, depending on what the file content and type of modification, a memory mapped file may also work VERY well for this purpose - but again, this completely avoids the `fstream` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load all the data of the file into memory, and pass a pointer to that memory instead. When done, simple write (the now modified) data back to the file.

Comment: This is clearly another alternative to my comment on the question.

Comment: This is actually what I'm doing - it seems that I was under the wrong impression that you could read & modify the files on the go with NASM.

Comment: @Omega You *can*, it's just very hard (especially with name mangling and such). Also, an `fstream` object is not the data of the file, and you can't use it as such.

Answer (score 1):

> I had heard that you could create an fstream, and send its pointer as
>   a parameter to a function in NASM, then you can operate over the bytes
>   in that pointer.

This works in principle, although different than you might have imagined. The contents of the file are not in memory so you cannot access them from assembly. You can however call the fstream's `read` member function from assembly to retrieve the data from the file.

Note that calling C++ member functions from assembly is quite a tricky thing, as the binary object model is not standardized and hence might change between different compilers. It's probably easier to use a lower-level interface (the C stdlib or the operating system's i/o functions) instead, as it's much easier to do C function calls from assembly.